# Parsing PHP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using php to consume a web service (in coldfusion) to validate against the active directory. My code is below.

```
<?php

$racf = $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];

//echo $racf;
//echo $myracf = trim($racf, "FEDERATED\.");


//get authenticated user
$arrUser = explode("\\", $_SERVER["LOGON_USER"]);
$racf = $arrUser[1];
echo $racf.'<br ><br >';

$logins = "http://acoldfusionwebservice/login.cfc?method=loginad&racf=$racf";

 if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file($logins) )
 {
    echo 'unable to load XML file';
 }
 else
 {
     //echo 'XML file loaded successfully <br />';  
    print_r ($xml);

 }
?>
```

And this produces the following.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.0
        )

    [header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [recordset] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [rowCount] => 1
                            [fieldNames] => cn,mail,givenName,sn
                        )

                     [field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => cn
                                        )

                                    [string] => B000000
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => mail
                                        )

                                    [string] => john.doe@company.com
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                             [name] => givenName
                                        )

                                    [string] => John
                                 )

                            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                     [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => sn
                                        )

                                    [string] => Doe
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Can someone help me to parse this information so that I can assign variables and use them.  Thanks.

Comment: It's XML that you've loaded into simplexml. YOu'd access it like anything else with simplexml... $xml->data->recordset->field[0] would be the cn/B0000 node

Comment: Which data you want to access?

Comment: I would like to access "B000000", "john.doe@company.com", "John", and "Doe".

Comment: I tried echo $xml->data->recordset->field[0];, but I didn't get a return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$xml->data->recordset->field[0]->string
```

I think that field[0] is an Object again